# Access specific column when deleting row from Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to access a specific column whenever i delete a row from my `DataGridView`. Whenever I click 'Hiq Porosin' a row is removed using:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
```

But whenever I do that, I need to access the 'Çmimi' column so I can remove its cost from the total.

[image: Screenshot of data]

Comment: So, look at the row and get the price first.  If you have a DataSource you *should* be working with that - the DGV is just the means to display stuff to the user.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

```
string cellValue = dataGridView1.Rows[item.Index].Cells[3].Value.ToString().Trim(); //  your 'Çmimi' Column index = 3
```

Comment: Adding a little explanation helps it understand better.